# Calling strange field of JSON in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, web-services, soap

im working with NodeJS and services SOAP in XML.

To call the soap I use strong-soap and to transform XML in JSON use xml2js.

All ready works good, the response shows like:

```
{ 'SOAP-ENV:Envelope':     { '$': 
      { 'xmlns:SOAP-ENV': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
        'xmlns:ns1': 'http://sandbox.coordinadora.com/agw/ws/guias/1.5/server.php',
        'xmlns:xsd': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
        'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        'xmlns:SOAP-ENC': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
        'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' },
     'SOAP-ENV:Body': [ [Object] ] } }
```

But in javascript I can call response.SOAP-ENV:Body because show me error.
What I can do to handle this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` and `:` aren't valid characters in javascript variables, so you'll have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) like this:

```
let body = response['SOAP-ENV:Body']
```